# How to search for regular expressions including backslashes and quotation marks in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to extract some text from a fairly unstructured text file read into R using the `readLines` function (The file is in .json format). I want to extract a regular expression which is contained in every line, and has the following pattern:

```
\"text\":\" some random text \"
```

I know that quotation marks and backslashes are essential for regular expressions, so I am lost as to how to search for them. I tried this:

```
text <- regexpr('\\\"text\\\":\\(*?)\\\"', charactervector)
```

but it didn't work.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try regexpr('\"text\":\" some random text \"', character vector)?

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply - i did try it, but it doesn't return any matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a more clear way to express this is

```
text <- regexpr('^[\\]"text[\\]":[\\]" some random text [\\]"', charactervector)
```

This assumes the literal input string `\"text\":\" some random text \"`

I did figure out how to get it working with just '\' characters but that is kind of ugly.

**EDIT**

Just a comment, I added the `^` to anchor at the beginning but it is not needed.

Comment: Thanks so much, this also worked! I suppose it's somewhat more easily navigable than John's method.

Answer (score 1):

Using lookbehind and lookahead:

```
s <- '\"text\":\" some random text \"'
m <- regexpr('(?<=\\\"text\":\\\" ).*(?= \\")' , s, perl = TRUE)
regmatches(s, m)
#[1] "some random text"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I have to admit I think this is slightly over my head and I find the other two answers more easily understandable, even though this one is probably more elegant

Answer (score 0):

Very close:

```
\\\"text\\\":\\\"(.*?)\\\"
```

Example here: https://regex101.com/r/fA2pW4/2

Comment: Thanks! awesome, this worked. The website is also really helpful. As @steveb said, it's not particularly beautiful, but it works!

Comment: this question is asking for the r flavor so please make your answer reflect that